# Weird thing in .dat file when using pickle

Tags: python-3.x, pickle

Ok so im using pickle and i want it to paste something to a .dat file, this is what i have as my output

```
€]q X   Workingqa.
```

My original code

```
import pickle

with open('writetofiletest.dat', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(["Working"], f, protocol=2)
```

But the thing is, the weird symbols interfere with what im trying to do

So, is there any alternatives to this or can i fix it?

Edit:
So the symbols arnt showing up in the post so, heres an image
[Weird Symbols](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YYifW.png)

Comment: Can you clarify what your goal is? The "weird symbols" are part of the pickle data. If you do not want them, pickle is not appropriate for your usecase. You can try `protocol=1`, but depending on what you consider "weird" this might still not be enough.

Comment: just write to the file?  `f.write( "Working" )`

Comment: My goal is to have python paste something into a .dat/.txt file without anything else with it
'pickle is not appropriate for your usecase'
I see, is there an alternative that is more appropriate for my goal?

Comment: As mention, why don't you just ``write`` to the file?